# How can I make use of WP Mobile Detect conditions from within a plugin?

Tags: plugins, mobile

I recently downloaded the WP Mobile Detect plugin and integrated it to my theme (the original mobile detect library I include from the theme folder and the matching WP-functions I pasted directly into `functions.php`).

Now I have one Social Share Plug-In I only want to appear when the site gets requested by desktop devices. So I tried modifying the core files of that plugin, wrapping the output function inside a condition of WP Mobile Detect, like:

```
if ( ! wpmd_is_phone() ) { // output my share buttons }
```

Unfortunately, this will return a `Call to undefined function`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to include/require the WPMD file that includes the function(s) you are using, or just use the globally defined `$detect` object, like so:

```
global $detect;
if (! $detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet()) {
    // output your share buttons
}
```

**// EDIT**
The above conditional is the equivalent of your `! wpmd_is_phone()` conditional. However, if you want to restrict this to desktop devices only, you should use the following:

```
global $detect;
if (! ($detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet())) {
    // output your share buttons
}
```

Comment: That's what I needed! Thank you very much for this! Sorry for honoring that late — my holidays came up ;-)